# Easiest way to log in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

In YII, when you want to log, you simply call:

```
YII::log("bla");
```

In Zend, I have to create a function:

```
private function log($message, $priority = Zend_Log::INFO)
{
    $logger = Zend_Registry::get("log");
    if( is_object($message) || is_array($message) )
        $logger->log( print_r( $message,true), $priority);
    else
        $logger->log( $message, $priority);
}
```

What is the easiest way to get a global function so that I can also easily log stuff as I do with YII. Is there perhaps a built in way whereby I can do something like this:

```
 ZEND::log("Bla");
```

Or how would I create such functionality and where would I put it in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your purpose is of the logging. I see three options:

1. Standard logging. if you want to log everything so you can check back who did what acction you should create a plugin and let it log, or make the database adapter log.

   an example of logging i did:

   ```
   class App_Plugin_Logger extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

   protected $fileLoc;
   public function __construct($file = null) {
       if($file ===null)
           $file = APPLICATION_PATH.'/../log/log_'.date('Y-m-d').'.txt';
       $this->fileLoc = $file;
   }

   public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
       $id = (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity() ? Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getId() : 0);

       $fp = fopen($this->fileLoc,"a");
       $message = date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' '.$request->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR').' USER:'.$id.' '.json_encode($request->getParams()).PHP_EOL;
           //logs all the input data (post/get), controller, action and ip-addres of client
       if(fwrite($fp,$message)===false){
           error_log('MagStream, Logging failed:'.$message);
       }
       fclose($fp);
   }
   }
   ```
2. If you just want to know a variable for debugging you can either `die(var_dump($variable));` or use the xdebug extension (very usefull)
3. If you want to log at specific places you could make a class of your own wich opens a file and adds a row at the end or use the zend_log library: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.log.overview.html

you could add a static function to Zend_Log:

```
public static function l($mes){
  $logger = new Zend_Log();
  $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('php://output'); 
  $logger->addWriter($writer);
  $logger->log($mes, Zend_Log::DEBUG);
}
```